# Axios PUT Request in React, Redux Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, put, axios

So I want to make a PUT request to the server, but it doesn't want to work. I know that when making a PUT request you need an identifier(e.g id) for the resource and the payload to update with.  So that is my problem.

In my form I have these props:

```
<div>
  <DoorSettingsForm
    onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}
    item={this.props.location.state.item}
    id={this.props.location.state.item._id}
  />
</div>
```

`item` - All the input fields, radiobuttons etc.

`id` - The identifier

`onSubmit` - the function that handles the submitting of all of the new data, here it is:

```
submit(values, id) {
  this.props.updateSettings(values, id)
}
```

And inside of my really simple action I have this:

```
export function updateSettings(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('ID: ', id)
    return axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, item)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

One thing that I really don't understand is when I change the places of `id` and `item` on the first line the output of my console.log changes. When having `id` as the first parameter I get everything I've typed in my inputs (the changes) and when having `item` as the first parameter  I'm getting this:

```
ID:  function (action) {
        if (action.payload) {
          if (!(0, _isPromise2.default)(action.payload) && !(0, _isPromise2.default)(action.payload.promise)) {
            return next(action);
          }
```

Any help with my problem is really appriciated! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call handleSubmit with my id:
`form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(id, item)}`